# Views PDF : class not found

Tags: 7, views

I am running Drupal 7.56

I have been using Views extensively for some months now. I want now to create custom pdf pages from some Views.

I have installed jQuery_update, then Views PDF Display Module, then copied fpdi and tcpdf libraries into the Libraries folder (via FTP).

Now, when I want to add a PDF Page to a View, I get the following error message :

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'sites/all/libraries/fpdi/fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php' (include_path='/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/nz.co.fuzion.cmcic-master/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/org.civicrm.sms.twilio/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/packages/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/paroisse/civi_extensions/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/default/fpdf:.:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:.:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules in /home/my_hostname/www/www/sites/all/modules/views_pdf/views_pdf_template.php on line 22

I suspect that this is due to a bad installation, but find no clear and up-to-date installation tutorial.

I must say that :
- I am not a programmer,
- I use civicrm, a big Drupal Module, which explains the big include path

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the entire fpdi folder into the libraries folder.

It should have multiple files. Check for fpdf_tpl.php. There should also be a filters folder into the fpdi folder.

Comment: I have downloaded FDPI-2.0.0.zip from www.setasign.com, dezipped on my PC, then transfered the whole fdpi folder to sites/all/libraries. But this fdpi contains no fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php nor fpdf_tpl.php (the src subfolder actually contains a FpdfTpl.php file (with no "_"))

Answer (score 2):

I went back to fpdi-1.6.2, and the error disappeared (the internal fpdi folder content has completely changed between the two versions).